# MacBook Air stopped connecting to WiFi

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

My MacBook Air suddenly stopped connecting to ANY WiFi. It worked fine earlier. I have not installed any software between these Two Stages. MacBook just says "Network Could not be joined. Try moving closer to the router.".
Other devices are able to connect to these WiFi networks.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried restarting it? Does it connect after a reboot?